# Splitting an Adobe Premier project

Tags: adobe-premiere

One of my coworkers has a fairly large (to us) amount of video in an Adobe Premier project. It appears to be running out of memory. I'm resident IT guru, but I have no experience with this program. How can we divide the project into multiple projects to cut down the memory use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a few things.

Under `Project` menu look for "remove unused clips" or something similar.

Also, you can create a trimmed project from that file as well.

I would recommend also, wrapping the videos into a larger single video file, so Premiere doesn't have to keep track of so many files internally. This makes a difference in my experience.

You can also try to increase your "page file" if you are on Windows.